# How to get the length of a file without downloading the file in a cURL binary get request

Tags: c++, curl

I want to create a cURL request in some C++ code which will get me the length of a file in a server without downloading the file. For that, I use some cURL options to tell I only want headers in the request response, and then I examine the response to get the file length.

I'm setting the following request options:

```
curl_easy_setopt(_curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(_curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
```

Then processing the request, waiting for the response, which shows a `OK=200`, and finally enquiring about the file length:

```
curl_easy_getinfo(_curl_handle, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_UPLOAD, &dResult);
```

But I get a file length of `-1`. According to cURL documentation, that means size is unknown. How can it happen that cURL doesn't get the file length information from the server?

Comment: It's not uncommon for that information not to be available.  Try running `curl --head` on the same URL from the command line, and see if it shows the file size.

Comment: If I do a `curl --head  "https://..."` it tells me `curl: (1) Protocol https not supported or disabled in libcurl`. If I try with `"http://"` or without `"http://"` it says `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host`.

Comment: Use `curl --version` to see what features curl.exe was compiled with. If `HTTPS` and `SSL` is not mentioned in the supported lists, then you cannot request `HTTPS` URLs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_UPLOAD` is the number of bytes uploaded.  You need to use `CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD` instead.

Note that if the server dynamically generates the data, the length may be different when you actualy download the file versus just downloading its headers.

Also note that if the server sends data as compressed when downloaded, there may not be any size available in the headers (if the `Transfer-Encoding` header is used instead of the `Content-Length` header), so `CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD` would still return `-1`.  The only way to know the size in that situation would be to download it in full.

Comment: I am using UPLOAD instead of DOWNLOAD because I found in several web pages that this term was misleading, and that if you wanted the size of a file that you are going to download you should use UPLOAD (it may make sense since you enquire about a file that has already been uploaded to the server).

Comment: Anyway, using DOWNLOAD I get the same result of `-1`.

Comment: BTW, debugging the code, I'm getting to a point within libcurl, the function `Curl_getinfo(struct SessionHandle *data, CURLINFO info, ...)` itself, where it checks `data->progress.flags`, and since they are null, it returns that `-1`. May it be that I am missing setting an option with `curl_easy_setopt`?

Comment: Is the server sending a success or failure response code? I would suggest using a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, to make sure libcurl is sending a valid request and see what kind of response it is receiving.

Comment: I cannot use wireshark because I'm sending https requests. However, my tool grabs the server output. What I see is:

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 213
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2011 10:52:31 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.5; JBoss-5.0/JBossWeb-2.1
Connection: keep-alive`

I always get a content-length of 213 for any binary I request.

Comment: The server is sending a `Content-length` header instead of `Content-Length`.  Make sure that is not tripping up libcurl's HTTP header parser somehow. Since libcurl is open-source, have you tried stepping through its source to see exactly how it parses the server's response?

Comment: I was using a session with no settings at all apart from the `CURLOPT_NOBODY`. Once I set the session up (proxy, user agent, and so on), I started receiving the correct content length for each binary I was requesting.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried with `CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD` instead?

Comment: Looks like that's deprecated and CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD_T is favored now.

Answer (score 3):

need call `perform()`

> curl_easy_setopt(_curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
>   curl_easy_setopt(_curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);

**curl_easy_perform(_curl_handle);**

> curl_easy_getinfo(_curl_handle, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_UPLOAD,
>   &dResult);

Comment: Should you need to both get header and body, it becomes a bit of a challenge in the curl_easy_perform - as you need to fetch/buffer the body (set CURLOPT_NOBODY appropriately), get then size, and then do appropriate things...